# vba excel. If / and

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I'm sure I'm going around this the wrong way by trying to paste a formula when it could be completed in the code but I'm an utter novice...

```
Range("W2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC[-17]=("Small"),COUNTIF(C[-18],RC[-18])=1),"WARNING","CLEAR")"
Range("W2").Select

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("W2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("W2:W" & lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Trying to get If `ColF = "Small"` and `ColV = 1` (that in itself is a pasted and copied down formula to check to see that the number of occurrences of `ColE` is just once) then display `WARNING` in `ColW`

Comment: I think you should replace your quotation marks: `"Small"` to `'Small'`

Comment: Use double quotations. `"Small"` should be `""Small""` and same for Warning and Clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the quotation marks. In general, this is how a `FormulaR1C1` should look like:

```
Public Sub TestMe
    Selection.formular1c1 = "=IF(1=1,""true"",""false"")"
End Sub
```

Make sure that you double the quotations, and it would work.

Cheers!